# Xcode 7 found a place where it prints a line with a log error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode7.3

I have a log in XCode output console:

```
Use -removeDeferredKeyObserver: instead of -removeKeyObserver:
```

I've searched trough the project using keyword `removeKeyObserver` but have not found any matches.

My question is how to found a place (line) after Xcode prints this line in console.

Comment: `find . -name \*.m -exec grep -l {} removeKeyObserver \;`

Answer (score 2):

As it can comes from a library or inside core frameworks, you should :

1. Open terminal
2. use `grep "removeKeyObserver:" * -r` to find where the method is called

It used this method today for about the same purpose.

Comment: David thanks for answer! as I understood I need to enter it right after opening terminal?) don't need to navigate to any folder. right?

Comment: You should navigate inside the root folder of your project before typing this. And you can adjust the search by changing down the hierarchy if you want.

Comment: ok yea it's helpful I found `grep "removeObserver:" * -r` but there is no result for `grep "removeKeyObserver:" * -r`